# Solution: ev.preventDefault is not a function when using dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I got something weird when I'm submitting a form.
When I'm using ev.preventDefault() as is, everything working as expected but when I'm adding dispatch to the function two lines later I'm getting the error: ev.preventDefault is not a function.
here are my code thanks in advance!

```
const addReview = async ev => {
  ev.preventDefault()
  if (!email || !message) return alert('All fields are required')
  await dispatch(addReview({email,message}))
  console.log('Adding review!');
}

<form onSubmit={addReview}>
  <input value={email} placeholder="Email" type="email" id="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange}/>
  <textarea
    name="message"
    placeholder="Message"
    rows="4"
    cols="50"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={message}
  ></textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Solved: The problem was caused by using the same name for the function in that component and on the actions page thanks all.

Comment: Was it working previously without the `dispatch` ***and*** `addReview` still declared `async`?

Comment: Why are calling addReview function from inside itself with dispatch?

Comment: Do you have thunk or saga there in place?

Comment: You have overwritten the `addReview` action with the  `addReview` form submit handler. Just give a different name to the submit handler.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes it was working without the dispatch and addReview still declared async

Comment: I think @GabrielePetrioli has it... your `addReview` function is masking the `addReview` action creator.

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi You got over the problem! I used the same name for the function in the actions I'm not sure but I guess a recursion was created. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shaul_b I'm glad I helped. Can I post my comment as an answer and you accept it?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli You was right thanks a lot!

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi Sure.

Comment: @ShaulBatzon Halooo

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling addReview function from inside itself with dispatch?

```
const addReview = async ev => {
  ev.preventDefault()
  if (!email || !message) return alert('All fields are required')
  await dispatch(?????({email,message})) // This line should be changed
  console.log('Adding review!');
}
```